# Resgatar registro de um input radio - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá, estou fazendo uma pagina de edição, e nela tenho um input `type="radio"`, e não estou conseguindo fazer o radio ser assinalado conforme o valor que está no banco de dados...

Estou tentando puxar dessa forma, porém não funciona, **sempre fica assinalado o que tem o valor `"F"`**, mesmo estando *M* no banco...

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM pacientes WHERE sus = '$sus' ");
while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>

    <div class="col">
    <label class="col-form-label">Sexo</label><p>
    <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="sexo" value="M" <?php if ($sexo = 'M') {echo ' checked ';} ?> />Masculino</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="sexo" value="F" <?php if ($sexo = 'F') {echo ' checked ';} ?> />Feminino</label>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

**Aonde estou errando?**

Comment: Você está atribuindo o valor M a variável $sexo, para comparar usa-se dois sinais de igual (==)

Comment: `=` define um valor ; `==` compara sem tipagem ; `===` compara com tipagem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consegui dessa forma:**

```
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M" <?php if($cont['sexo']=="M"){ echo "checked";}?> />Masculino</label>
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="F" <?php if($cont['sexo']=="F"){ echo "checked";}?> />Feminino</label>
```